# Login and Roles in Asp.Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm finally leaving webforms behind and upgrading to .net core. Problem is, I have searched about login and roles in .net core and it seems to rely on the Identity database... I don't want to create all these tables. I used to just do forms authentication and store roles on form authentication ticket. Is there something similar to this in asp.net core razor pages?

I also have done the razor pages tutorial from Microsoft but doesn't go much into detail about this.

Comment: There's some new tables for things like claims, external login providers, etc. which Membership (the old ASP.NET system) didn't support. However, there were still tables backing Membership in your database. Roles were persisted to the database, and then merely added to the auth cookie after authentication. That process still exists via Cookie Auth in Identity, which is basically the same thing as Forms Auth was in Membership.

Comment: For built-in Identity, you could not custom to remove the extra tables. You could implement your own authentication middleware.

Comment: You mean i could use the identity still but with my own custom tables in sql?